# Setting font in emacs-daemon

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have this line in my .emacs:

```
(set-face-font 'default "-unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-bold-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
```

when I run emacs daemon and start my usual way, with emacs-daemon:

```
error: Font not available, #font-spec nil unknown DejaVu Sans Mono nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 13 nil 100 0 ((:name . -unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-bold-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1) (user-spec . -unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-bold-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1))
```

I get the same error with the "emacs -nw".

It's fairly clear what is happening: the emacs daemon session is not a x session. So it fails to pick up an X font. But then how do I setup things so this is the default font when an emacs client connects from an X session?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it through `custom`:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :height 100 :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")))))
```